# Finding angle using three points

Tags: java, math, lwjgl

I want a square (represented by `head`) to always face toward the mouse (represented by `Mouse` - yeah, it's LWJGL). I'm having a bit of trouble actually getting it to face torward the mouse because i'm using `glRotatef(angle)`, which

1. Requires degrees, while most java `Math` functions involve radians
2. Is difficult to do since I have no way of knowing how far i have to rotate in order to point toward the mouse

I whipped up the following java code, which assumes that 0 degrees is straight up:

```
double mx = Mouse.getX();
double my = Mouse.getY();
double rx = head.x;
double ry = head.y + 1;
double vx = head.x;
double vy = head.y;
double mtor = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mx + rx, 2) + Math.pow(my + ry, 2));
double mtov = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mx + vx, 2) + Math.pow(my + vy, 2));
double rtov = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rx + vx, 2) + Math.pow(ry + vy, 2));
double rotate = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((Math.pow(mtov, 2) + Math.pow(rtov, 2) - Math.pow(mtor, 2))/(2*mtov*rtov))));
```

However, this creates some strange results:

[image: What]

(The side with the white squares is the front. For a full album go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT0Rq.jpg)

Here's some console output:

```
Mouse X: 555.0
Mouse Y: 439.0
Reference X: 400.0
Reference Y: 301.0
Vertex X: 400.0
Vertex Y: 300.0
Rotation: 65.56236879269605

Mouse X: 552.0
Mouse Y: 440.0
Reference X: 400.0
Reference Y: 301.0
Vertex X: 400.0
Vertex Y: 300.0
Rotation: 65.5244609346555
```

So, what am I doing wrong? (Extra Credit: is there some better way to do this in openGL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that 0 degrees is straight up, counterclockwise is positive, that x increases to the right, and that y increases upward. (I don't know if that's true for LWJGL.) I'm using a range of -180 to 180, rather than 0 to 360, since that seems more natural (eg, if the head were to slowly rotate)

```
double dx = (mx-vx); // change in x from head to mouse
double dy = (my-vy); // change in y from head to mouse
double dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); // distance, pythagorean theorem
double degrees = Math.toDegrees((Math.acos(dy/dist)) * -Math.signum(dx));
        // dy/dist is the cosine
        // the sign of dx determines positive (CCW) or negative (CW) angle
```

If you're worried about performance, you could avoid a sqrt operation by using atan, but you'd need to do extra tests to determine the quadrant and to avoid dividing by zero. It'd still probably be a hair faster, but might not be worthwhile.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about what I'm doing.

Comment: This always returns a value of either -45 or 135.

Comment: Did you mean for `double dy = (my-vy);`? It works if I do this. Thank you!